# How to add an alias to java.security.Provider?

Tags: java, security, gost3410

I need to verify digital signature in a pdf file.
I use `itextpdf` and `cryptopro`

`cryptopro` provides these aliases for the needed algorithm:

```
, JCP: Signature.GOST3411withGOST3410EL -> ru.CryptoPro.JCP.Sign.GostElSign
  aliases: [1.2.643.2.2.3, OID.1.2.643.2.2.3, 1.2.643.2.2.9with1.2.643.2.2.19]
```

`itextpdf` tries to get "GOST3411withECGOST3410" and fails with: "no such algorithm: GOST3411withECGOST3410 for provider JCP"

This works:

```
Provider prov = Security.getProvider(PROVIDER_NAME);
prov.put("Alg.Alias.Signature.GOST3411withECGOST3410", "GOST3411withGOST3410EL");
```

Not sure it's a correct way though.

```
Exception in thread "main" ExceptionConverter: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: GOST3411withECGOST3410 for provider JCP
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:70)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:190)
    at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:324)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7.initSignature(PdfPKCS7.java:692)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7.<init>(PdfPKCS7.java:452)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(AcroFields.java:2349)
    at org.foo.PdfVerifier.verify(PdfVerifier.java:83)
    at org.foo.PdfVerifier.main(PdfVerifier.java:53)
```

Comment: Could you post the full trace of NoSuchAlgorithmException exception stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is Ok and practically you have no other choice.

However, the true problem lies in the way `itextpdf` works. It hardcodes BouncyCastle's names for key algorithms `ECGOST3410`, while CryptoPro JCP has the `GOST3410EL` name for the same algorithm. This makes it difficult to switch to use keys produced by different security provider like in your case.

The library can get the same values from keys using [Key.getAlgorithm()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html#getAlgorithm%28%29), which will eliminate the need for hardcoding and make the library less "security provider dependent."
Hardcoding is an especially bad idea taking into account that [PdfPKCS7](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/security/PdfPKCS7.html#PdfPKCS7%28java.security.PrivateKey,%20java.security.cert.Certificate%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalDigest,%20boolean%29) constructor allows security provider selection.

Comment: Strange that they don't use OIDs instead of names here